# Use sed to modify a key=value config file

Tags: sed

I have a config file with parameters like below

```
INPUT                  =
RECURSIVE              = NO
GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
```

so I used the `sed` command to replace/modify the value as below

```
sed -i 's/.*INPUT                  =.*/INPUT                  = something/' doxygen.conf
sed -i 's/.*RECURSIVE              = NO.*/RECURSIVE              = YES/' doxygen.conf
sed -i 's/.*GENERATE_LATEX         = YES.*/GENERATE_LATEX         = NO/' doxygen.conf
```

But this relies on exactly matching the spacing, which might change. Is there a more robust way to do this?

Comment: Why does it look "bad"? For aesthetic reasons or do you think it's unreliable?

Comment: What do you mean by "looks very bad"? Which version of doxygen are you using? Are yo using CMake in your build process? There are a number of things one can do. In the exampleyou can already replace in the search part the `     ` parts with `  *`. You don't have to use `sed` you can add the new values like `GENERATE_LATEX         = NO` at the end of the doxygen.conf (e.g. by means of the `echo` command. You could use environment variables (and address them like `${...)`).

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: bad here means it could be unreliable if I miss a single space, it wont work so, I want to explore if there is  more smarter sed expression ?

Answer (score 2):

Repeat what I'm doing here for the INPUT line for your other lines:

```
$ sed 's/^\(INPUT[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 something/' file
INPUT                  = something
RECURSIVE              = NO
GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex [address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html) to match the lines you want, and then only concern yourself with the text after the =:

```bash
sed -i -e '/^INPUT[ =]/s/=.*/= something/' \
    -e '/^RECURSIVE[ =]/s/=.*/= YES/' \
    -e '/^GENERATE_LATEX[ =]/s/=.*/= NO/' \
    doxygen.conf
```

So the command `/^INPUT[ =]/s/=.*/= something/` first finds the line that starts with "INPUT " or "INPUT=", and then runs the substitute command on the second half of the line, replacing "=.*" with "= something".

Given this input:

```
INPUT                  =
RECURSIVE              = NO
GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
```

We get this output:

```
INPUT                  = something
RECURSIVE              = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one liner:

`sed -E 's/(INPUT[ ]+=[ ]*).*/\1YES/;s/(RECURSIVE[ ]+=[ ]*).*/\1YES/;s/(GENERATE_LATEX[ ]+=[ ]*).*/\1NO/' doxygen.conf`